# localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500 - For asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have been trying to get my head around trying to solve this problem and I have looked online to find relevant information on this. I was unable to resolve this.

My application does use a web API that was already existing as a template for this project. I think this might be causing the problem. I do not have much experience with this and I am running out of ideas to resolve this.

An additional question would be how to use other controllers without having the web API configurations active.

The web page shows the error with the url: https://localhost:(number removed)/api

If anyone needs any other code to be seen, please do ask and I will edit the post as I am not too sure where all is needed to look.

My Start up file:

```
    public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {   
        
        // ** Add Cookie Authentication via extension method **
        //services.AddCookieAuthentication();

        // ** Add Cookie and Jwt Authentication via extension method **
        services.AddCookieAndJwtAuthentication(Configuration);

        // ** Enable Cors for and webapi endpoints provided **
        services.AddCors();
        
        // Add UserService to DI - change to use real UserService           
        services.AddTransient<SolutionNameService,SolutionNameServiceDb>();

        // ** Required to enable asp-authorize Taghelper **            
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            //app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();


            // seed users - using service provider to get UserService from DI
            Seeder.Seed(provider.GetService<SolutionNameService>());
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        // ** configure cors to allow full cross origin access to any webapi end points **
        app.UseCors(c => c.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());

        // ** turn on authentication/authorisation **
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        
    }


}
```

Program file

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

ApiUserController

```
// ** This is a Demo WebAPI Controller provides User Login Using JWT Token **

[ApiController]    
[Route("api")]     
// set default auth scheme as we are using both cookie and jwt authentication
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class UserApiController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IPatientHutService _svc;       
    private readonly IConfiguration _config; // jwt settings
  
    public UserApiController(IPatientHutService service, IConfiguration _configuration)
    {      
        _config = _configuration;            
        _svc = service;
    }

    // POST api/login
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("login")]
    public ActionResult<User> Login(UserLoginViewModel login)        
    {                     
        var user = _svc.Authenticate(login.Email, login.Password);            
        if (user == null)
        {
            return BadRequest(new { message = "Email or Password are incorrect" });
        }
        // sign jwt token to use in secure api requests
        var authUser = SignInJwt(user);

        return Ok(authUser);
    }  

    // POST api/login
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("register")]
    public ActionResult<User> Register(UserRegisterViewModel reg)        
    {                     
        var user = _svc.AddUser(reg.Name, reg.Email, reg.Password, reg.Role);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return BadRequest(new { message = "User Could not be Registered" });
        }
        // sign jwt token to use in secure api requests
        var authUser = SignInJwt(user);

        return Ok(authUser);
    }  

    // Sign user in using JWT authentication
    private UserAuthenticatedViewModel SignInJwt(User user)
    {
        return new UserAuthenticatedViewModel
        {
            Id = user.Id,
            Name = user.Name,
            Email = user.Email,              
            Role = user.Role,
            Token = AuthBuilder.BuildJwtToken(user, _config),
        };
    }     

}
```

Comment: Can you post the the exception stack trace or the screen error?

Comment: @GabrielFrancisco When I build the project no issues are found or shows any errors but the web page on google shows the 500 error and says the localhost cannot handle the error. If there is another way in visual studio to get up on what you ask. Let me know and I will post it immediately

Comment: Feels like a startup failure because the GetRequiredService call in Configure is very suspicious. In case that is the cause, then in the signature of the Configure method, you can just dependency inject the service like so: `Configure(INeededDependency, IOtherStuff)

Comment: HTTP status code 500 means "internal server error", you should check that error inforrmation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the IPatientHutService and the implementation in the ConfigureServices method.

To view detailed error messages, uncomment the line.

```
//app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
```

Comment: That would not fix the problem (this should not be an answer), but it would be a good comment in the question so OP uses it and can edit the question with the actual error he/she got.

Comment: @Cleptus, I agree, but at that time, I didn't have enough points to make a comment.

Comment: @GabrielFrancisco and everyone! Thank you all for commenting, but I was able to fix the issue myself. Uncommenting the app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage did help!